# Не работает сборка gulp фрилансера по жизни

Tags: javascript, gulp

Ну в общих чертах, скачал сборку **фрилансера по жизни**, все установил, прописываю **npm run dev**, и не  работает модуль **del**, я его откатил на 6 версию, иии казалось бы все заработало, но не создается папка **dist**. В чем проблема?
p.s если надо все скрины скину

Comment: К сожалению, `"сборка фрилансера по жизни"` не является каким-то стандартом, общепризнанным авторитетом или общеизвестным понятием, чтобы на него можно было ссылаться, предполагая, что все сразу поймут о чем речь.

Comment: Приведите детали этой сборки, конкретную конфигурацию, настройки, полученные в результате выполнения команд ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Там в режиме разработчика отключено создание папки выгрузки,
в файле настроек вебпака, версии `DEV`, есть комментарий, который включит эту функцию, но тогда не будут работать стили (сборка кривая):

откатывать `del` не нужно!

Решение:

> SyntaxError: The requested module 'del' does not provide an export
> named 'default'

> import {deleteAsync as del} from 'del'; во всех файлах конфигурации

Answer (score 0):

Папка `dist` создается после команды - `npm run build`